# When using parameter for join clause in snowflake, getting wrong result. why?

Tags: sql, join, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbeaver

I'm using dbeaver with connection to snowflake database.
I want to select data with join clause.
but I need to do it with parameters.
my code is:

```
select count(*) from my_table as a ${join}

var join = 'LEFT JOIN table_b AS b ON a.ID = b.ID AND b.NAME = a.NAME'
```

when I run the *select* statement (in dbeaver), I get pop up asking me to fill `${join}` value,
I put the value in the textbox and the command runs. I get WRONG result! (1,254,242)

But when run the following command:

```
select count(*) from my_table as a LEFT JOIN table_b AS b ON a.ID = b.ID AND b.NAME = a.NAME
```

I get correct result (900,254)

anybody can help please? thank you.

Comment: WIth `LEFT JOIN`  and `COUNT(*)` you are efectively always counting the rows from my_table. If the code is really the same(which I doubt because it is dummy code) then other possibilites are: 1) Row level security 2) Different databases/schemas

Comment: I suggest to check the [Snowflake History](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/ui-history.html) and compare the exact SQL code sent by dbeaver with that run directly in webUI.

Comment: @ Lukasz Szozda I know its weird, but it is the same code. I copy paste it from same place and checked it dozens of times. can you please explain your option 1> bacuse this is the same database.

Comment: Row level security allows to hide some data depending which user is connecting to database. For instance userA can see content of entire table, but userB only single department. Please check you use exactly the same user/role to connect to SF on DBeaver/WebUI `SELECT current_user(), current_role()`

Comment: thank you all. @Lukasz Szozda- you did help, it was a good idea to check snowflake history... the dummy issue came from var join = 'xxx... \n
lll' and because of the enter- was all the mess. thanks again.

Comment: Glad to hear that. I have complied it as an answer(it may be useful for others too). You could consider [Accpeting answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0):

General approach to troubleshoot such scenarios:

1. Check if you are connecting to the same DB/schema from client tool/WebUI

   ```
    SELECT current_database(), current_schema();
   ```
2. Check if you are using the same user(there may be access issues or Row Level Security applied that could affect number of rows)

   ```
   SELECT current_user(), current_role();
   ```
3. Check the exact query text sent by client tool in [Snowflake History tab](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/ui-history.html) and compare against the one run manually.