# ODBC can't access the output from a query in snowflake

Tags: odbc, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, rodbc

Hi i have a weird issue where i can see my table in connection tab within R studio but when i tried to query it, the error is `the table does not exist or not authorized.` I can access other production table under the same warehouse.

Comment: [I would first check current_db/schema/user/role and query history](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67198823/5070879)

Comment: Thanks @LukaszSzozda i checked the database and schema and it returned as NA and the role is transformer for me

Comment: Are you able to query that table with same user from Snowflake UI?